# Update Multiple ROW by Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, sql-update

I have more than 2000 data but I entered the status number incorrectly. I should enter 1 (deployed) but I use 2 (In Inventory).

How do I change the status from 2 to 1 with thousands of data?

I'm trying with this code

```
UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_serial_number = '1'

UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_serial_number = '2';

UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_serial_number = '3';

UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_serial_number = '3';

UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_serial_number = '4';
```

Comment: Why do you use strings for columns which logically should be integral?

Comment: I want change ae_status  from 2 to 1.

Comment: @biiboy is that for **all** the data in your table?

Comment: not at all. I want change 2093 data from 15 thousands.

Comment: Are the serial numbers consecutive?

Comment: Hi @Nick the serial number is not consecutive. I wrong insert random. Ex. ABC123, DER421, REF768.

Comment: And I presume there are other records in your table that should legitimately have `ae_status=2`?

Comment: yes that's right. I have more than 3 thousands with ae_status=2. and I checked today and it turns out there were 2093 that I entered incorrectly. now, I want to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you cannot simply execute:

```
UPDATE
    asset_existing
SET
    ae_status = '1'
WHERE
    ae_serial_number IN ('1', '2', '3', ...)
    AND ae_status = '2'
;
```

?

I've added `ae_status = '2'` in where clause to be on a safe side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of records that have ae_status = 2 and you want to change them to 1

```
UPDATE asset_existing
SET
ae_status = '1'
WHERE ae_status = '2';
```

Comment: is it more than 1 the serial number ?